# Reference output from an online nested module within a nested module

Tags: terraform

I have the following file structure:

```
├── lambda
│   ├── main.tf
├── main.tf
```

`main.tf` creates the `my_custom_lambda_function` module off of the `lambda` folder.

```
module "my_custom_lambda_function" {
  source = "./lambda"
  function_name = "some-name"
}
```

Then, I have a nested module within `lambda` that refers to an online module:

```
# lambda/main.tf
variable "function_name" {
  type = string
}

module "lambda_template" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"
  function_name = "{var.function_name}"
}
```

I need to access an output in the module `module.lambda_template` from `module.my_custom_lambda_function`. However, when I try to do this:

```
# lambda/main.tf
output "function_arn" {
  value = module.lambda_template.this_lambda_function_arn
}
```

I get the following error:

```
No module call named "lambda_function" is declared in the root module.
```

Which makes sense, because this syntax is referring to a module within the root. But I want to access the module that is **relative to the module that I'm currently on**. I have not yet found a way to do this. Something like:

```
# lambda/main.tf
output "function_arn" {
  value = module.${this}.module.lambda_function.this_lambda_function_arn
}
```

Where the value of `this` would be `my_custom_lambda_function`.

This code is not valid syntax, but it expresses what I need. Is there a way to do this within Terraform?

Comment: Can you please clarify your setup? if `output "function_name"` is in `A/main.tf` as you wrote, it all should work. And how is `main.tf` used? It is not shown in your code. What do you do in `main.tf` to create `module "A"`?

Comment: Hey @Marcin I went ahead and added some clarifications. Essentially, I need to access an output from a module that is nested two levels deep.

Comment: So the `module.${this}.module.lambda_function.this_lambda_function_name` is called from root `main.tf`, or `A/main.tf` as you wrote?

Comment: Or maybe, what is your root `main.tf`. There is nothing wrong with your `lambda/main.tf`.

Comment: Nope, it's called from my module one level in. But there apparently is something wrong, because the error that I'm getting is that it needs to be declared in the root module.

Comment: Apologies; I removed the reference to `A/main.tf`. I meant `lambda/main.tf`. Essentially, I need the `my_custom_lambda_function` module to expose an output of a submobule within `my_custom_lambda_function`.

Comment: Can you please add a bit of code showing root `main.tf`. How do you create your module there? How do you access its outputs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228925/discussion-between-dimiguel-and-marcin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments and chat discussion.

I tried to **replicate** the setup, and I found **nothing wrong** with it. It all works as expected.

It also works now for the OP. Upon chat discussion, the issue could had been caused before by a **spelling mistake** in module or output names.